# when I click a button in a list of buttons, it changes all of them instead of only one -Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a problem with changing the text inside a button when clicked

I have a list of buttons in my HTML displaying  a list of angular material:

```html
<table *ngIf="buildingImageList.length 0" mat-table [dataSource]="buildingImageList" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="finishDate">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Estimated Finish </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.finishDate | date: 'medium'}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="buildId">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Cancel </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <button mat-flat-button color="accent
 (click)="cancelBuildingImage(element.buildId); setCancelingText($event)">
            {{content}}
      </button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

My `.ts`

```js
export class BuildingImagesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  buildingImageList: BuildingImage[];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ["tag", "created", "startedBuilding", "finishDate", "buildId"];

  content: string;

  constructor(private builderService: BuilderService, private snackMessageService: SnackMessageService) {
    this.content = "Cancel build"
  }
  setCancelingText($event) {
    this.content = "Canceling..."
  }

  private populateBuildingImageList(): void {
    this.builderService.getBuildingImageList().then(response => {
      this.buildingImageErrorMessage = null;
      this.buildingImageList = response;
      this.convertDurationToDate();
    }).catch(() => {
      this.buildingImageErrorMessage = "Oops, there was an error getting the company list.";
    });
  }

public cancelBuildingImage(buildId: string): void {
    console.log("button pressed")
    this.builderService.cancelBuildingImage(buildId).then(() => {
      this.snackMessageService.sendMessage("Build canceled.");
      this.populateBuildingImageList(); // No se si es necesario, porque ya se llama en el builder.service
    }).catch(() => {
      this.buildingImageErrorMessage = "Oops, there was an error canceling the image build."
    });
  }
```

Clicking one button changes the text of all my button settings and the value is canceled.

How do I change only one-button text when clicked? The `dataSource` is an object with the keys displayed as columns (example: `finishDate`) and it doesn't allow me to interact with the text button.

Answer (score 0):

`{{content}}` should be something like `{{element.content}}`. Click event functions should also need to change accordingly

Comment: Hi Canvax, sorry, I edited my question to show the problem. The dataSource is not allowing me to interact with the button text separately....

Comment: then you should change corresponding `buildingImageList` element

Comment: Thank, the problem is that I don't know how to do  it

Answer (score 0):

Within the function `setCancelingText`, `this` doesn't refer to the button or the event, but the class of the component you're currently operating in. Because of this, you're changing the text of the `content`-variable for all buttons.

My approach to correct this would work like this:

Within the model `BuildingImage`, add a property for the cancel-button's text:*
`cancelButtonText?: string;`

Change the `populateBuildingImageList` function to define the empty properties when they arrive in your component:

```js
  private populateBuildingImageList(): void {
    this.builderService.getBuildingImageList().then(response => {
      this.buildingImageErrorMessage = null;

      for (let item of response) {
        item.cancelButtonText = "Cancel build";
      }

      this.buildingImageList = response;
      this.convertDurationToDate();
    }).catch(() => {
      this.buildingImageErrorMessage = "Oops, there was an error getting the company list.";
    });
  }
```

Then change the button like this:

```html
<button mat-flat-button color="accent"
        (click)="cancelBuildingImage(element.buildId); setCancelingText(element);">
  {{element.cancelButtonText}}
</button>
```

Finally, change the `setCancelingText`-function to this:

```js
setCancelingText(element) {
  element.cancelButtonText = "Canceling...";
}
```

Personally I would also include the changing of the cancel-button into the `cancelBuildingImage` function, but you didn't share what it does and whether the `setCancelingText` function is called from somewhere else, so I left it in place.

*) I assume here that `BuildingImage` is a class. If it is an interface, you'd need to add the text when you create the object.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question, to show what  cancelBuildingImage does. It's the way to pass the id of the image I want to camcel.

Comment: Doesn't look like it would conflict with my solution. Have you tried it?

Comment: I have tried. The model is interface type, and I can only write type string for cancelButtonText. No idea where to set the element. cancelButtonText = "cancel build" which is the initial value

Comment: In your `builderService`, you at some point get the data to create the objects. You can then iterate over the new objects with a for...each loop to fill in the text.

Comment: Alternatively, fill the properties in the `populateBuildingImageList` function - I've added this approach to the answer.